# 20 inch wheels and spoke tension measurement tool

Tags: wheels, spokes, wheel-building, wheel-truing, tension

I got a ParkTool TM-1 but it doesn't fit on the wheel I am trying to check (20 inch).

How do people deal with smaller wheels when it comes to checking spoke tension?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Personally I don't measure spoke tension with anything more complex than tapping the spoke with the spoke key, and squeezing adjacent pairs while de-stressing/relieving tension.

I have built two 20" wheels, and its just the same as larger wheels, an iterative process of tightening each nipple a bit until it becomes truing more than assembling.  The main difference is smaller wheels tend to have fewer spoke crossings than larger wheels which are often 3-cross.

If you spin the wheel and lightly hold a hard object near the spokes, a grazing touch should result in  "tink-tink-tink-tink" and any standount <sup>TINK!</sup> or <sub>thonk</sub> should be checked closer.

Wheel building is not an exact science, often you'll be making compromises on tension across spokes, to get the rim as true as possible.